# PHP: making a copy of a reference variable

Tags: php

If I make a copy of a reference variable. Is the new variable a pointer or does it hold the value of the variable the pointer was referring to?

Comment: References are not pointers. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Comment: Sometimes you must use them, for instance when implementing offsetget. Though no doubt that references in PHP are a mess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It holds the value. If you wanted to point, use the `&` operator to copy another reference:

```php
$a = 'test';
$b = &$a;
$c = &$b;
```

Comment: Don't say "point". he'll think there's some difference between $a, $b and $c (like a pointer and a pointed).

Answer (score 8):

Let's make a quick test:

```
<?php

$base = 'hello';
$ref =& $base;
$copy = $ref;

$copy = 'world';

echo $base;
```

Output is `hello`, therefore `$copy` isn't a reference to `%base`.

Comment: Which should be expected - the point of `$ref` being a reference to `$base` is that `$copy = $ref` should have the exact same effect as `$copy = $base`.

Comment: This made me understand references far better. For some reason i though that to copy a reference you could `$copy = $ref;`. Now i understand that is like a dereference and copies the data that the reference references. I think using C pointers makes this confusing as you have to dereference manually.

Comment: @Lightbulb1: That's because PHP's references are more like C++ references than C/C++ pointers. ;)

Comment: Pointers and references are very confusing. I think i'm getting there haha

Answer (score -1):

Let me murk the water with this example:

```
$a = array (1,2,3,4);
foreach ($a as &$v) {

}
print_r($a);

foreach ($a as $v) {
  echo $v.PHP_EOL;
}
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   [3] => 4
)

1
2
3
3

Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
   [3] => 3
)
```

Comment: Your example is **intentionally confusing**. after `foreach ($anything as &$v) {}` variable `$v` will hold the reference to last array element (while this is confusing, it's correct behavior), you should either `unset($v)` or keep in mind that `$v` is a reference. **Pro-tip: use var_dump() instead of print_r(), it will show &references in arrays**