# Clone an array passed by reference

Tags: php, arrays

There is this function taking the `$feedback` argument by reference and modifying it:

```
private function removeEmptyAnswers(&$feedback)
{
    //Do stuff with $feedback
}
```

I would like to make a copy of `$feedback` before it gets changed, to log it:

```
private function removeEmptyAnswers(&$feedback)
{
    $feedbackCopy = $feedback;
    //Do stuff with $feedback
    MyLog::write(['before' => $feedbackCopy, 'after' => $feedback]);
}
```

This would be peanuts if `$feedback` were passed by value, but it is passed by reference, meaning that my `$feedbackCopy` will also get changed.. or not?

Strange enough not to find any solution for this after 30 minutes of googling.

**How to make a copy of an array, which is passed by reference?**

Comment: `$feedbackCopy` would not be changed when you change `$feedback`. https://3v4l.org/072Pi So you don't have to change anything actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is enough to just assign the array to another variable.

```
$original = [1, 2, 3];
function meh (&$arr) { $copy = $arr; $copy[0] = 'meh'; }
meh($original);
var_dump($original); // unchanged

function meh1(&$arr) { $arr[0] = 'meh'; }
meh1($original);
var_dump($original); // changed
```

The original array is not changed in that case, as you see. But if you change the argument, it is changed, as expected.

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840112/php-making-a-copy-of-a-reference-variable) for more information, as suggested by [AnthonyB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4932315/anthonyb).

Comment: And once again, PHP generates the *least expected result*. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840112/php-making-a-copy-of-a-reference-variable) if you copy a reference without  reference operation, the reference copy is not a reference.